# MutableStateFlow difference between value and emit

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

What is the difference between using value and emit functions on a MutableStateFlow?

```
fun main() = runBlocking {

    val mutable = MutableStateFlow(0)

    launch {
        mutable.collect {
            println(it)
        }
    }

    mutable.value = 1
    mutable.emit(2)
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`emit()` is a suspend function that wraps a call to set the value:

```
override suspend fun emit(value: T) {
    this.value = value
}
```

So the difference is that `value` lets you set the value even when not in a coroutine. `emit()` exists so MutableStateFlow can inherit from MutableSharedFlow.

[Source code here.](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/edd584acb852d4b403173d168ea036510d1e1109/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/flow/StateFlow.kt#L324)

Comment: When to use `emit` instead of `value`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky since they do exactly the same thing, it doesn’t matter. IMO, it’s clearer to use `value` since it doesn’t suspend on a MutableStateFlow.

Comment: but it's not about main thread as in `LiveData`'s `value` and `postValue`?

Comment: @user924, no. `MutableStateFlow.value` is threadsafe.